# When I resume a paused VM in Fusion the svchost process starts chewing up CPU indefinitely

Tags: vmware, vmware-fusion

I found that when I start up a paused VM in Fusion, sometimes the svchost process slams one of the CPUs allocated to the VM. It never seems to "right" itself and just sits there and cranks away. It appears that it's a low-priority operation, but it definitely stresses out my host system's CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Although not directly related, this article: https://communities.vmware.com/message/2324577 helped me out quite a bit. I downloaded Process Explorer from Microsoft's Windows Sysinternals set, which allowed me to identify exactly the process running under the svchost "umbrella" and isolate the problem.

I'm not running XP, but the problem ended up being the task scheduler, specifically two running tasks under Microsoft > Windows > CertificateServicesClient called "SystemTask" and "UserTask". Setting those to disabled immediately stopped the CPU drain, even though they still showed as "running" after a refresh. No idea if it's a good idea to turn those off, but for a development / non-production machine I'm okay with that.

I'm running Windows 2008 Server in this particular instance.